# In ScrollView EditText is getting Unnecessary focus

Tags: java, android

I have a layout which i have used for a fragment:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ll_root_view"
    app:theme="@style/SpennTheme.Light.NoActionBar">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/createBusinessTb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_screen">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profilePicHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="216dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/storePicIv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_store_image" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upload_pic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_accent_circle"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_edit" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/editbusiness_focus_thief"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <requestFocus />
            </View>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/createBusinessHeadingTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:background="@color/pale_grey_three"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_margin"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_margin"
                android:text="Information"
                android:textColor="@color/gunmetal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputContent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameTil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:hint="Name on map"
                app:hintEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameEt"
                    style="@style/EditTextProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:lines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputContent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameTil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:hint="Name on map"
                app:hintEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/addressEt"
                    style="@style/EditTextProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:lines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                style="@style/ButtonStyleInactive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:text="Create" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am clearing focus after the done button of my keyboard like below:

```
et1.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    NKeyboardController.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                    et1.getTextInput().clearFocus();
                    et1.getTextInput().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

et2.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    NKeyboardController.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                    et2.getTextInput().clearFocus();
                    et2.getTextInput().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

B**ut the second one is alway focusing to first edittext after the clicking on done button of the keyboard.**

I have tried to remove focus from parent view like this in the keyboard action:

```
rootView.clearFocus();
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

But nothing is helping me here. Need suggestions here.

Comment: Maybe you could try this: set following attributes to your CoordinatorLayout: focusable="true" and clickable="true". When you clear forcus from your edit text, it will try to focus first focus able element in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable edit text focus by using below code on your main layout

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/autotext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

clear focus from `et1` and also request focus when it goes touch

```
et1.setOnEditorActionListener((v1, actionId, event) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            et1.clearFocus();
            et1.requestFocusFromTouch();
        }
        return false;
});
```

Suggestion : No need to hide keyboard when you click done editor option